# can I install CPanel with ip local?

Tags: 14.04, networking, panel, vps

I have bought a VPS, but when I execute `ifconfig` it shows me a local IP for the VPS and my static IP doesn't appear.
Can I install `cPanel` or `plesk` with that configuration?
If not , what should I do to get a static IP?

I have no idea about networking but that is the scene:

`/etc/network/interfaces`
[image: Terminal screenshot]

[image: Terminal screenshot (networking)]

Excuse me for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more geared towards Cpanel then Ubuntu.  Also Cpanel doesn't support Ubuntu.

Interworx has support for Ubuntu and does something similar though.
http://www.interworx.com/

If you want to set a static ip then just edit this file

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Not sure what your file will look exactly like, but you need to have it look similar to this.

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter your ip here)
        netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter gateway ip here,usually the address of the router)
```

ISPConfig has tutorials on this as well.
https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3

**What is a static IP(basically)**
If you want to use a static IP locally then you can just set it to what ever you like as long as it isn't used about another device.  For example change the value to be 
192.168.1.200

Now after you set it to that IP it will never change as opposed to DHCP which will dynamically assign the IP based on what ever logic your router has in place.

If you want an external static IP then you will need to purchase one from your ISP.

If you cannot purchase a static IP for what ever reason you can still get around this by using a service and program to help with this process.  You can use a service like something here - http://dyn.com/dns/

After you change the IP in that file make sure you reset the service that reads in the config file you altered.

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: yes it is right but what about other panel like Ispconfig or any panel

Comment: nano /etc/network/interfaces show me just "auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback"

Comment: i updated the answer for you

Comment: You don't magically get a static IP.  You either set it yourself and use it locally, or you need to purchase a static IP from your ISP.

Comment: I have purchased static ip but it doesn't appear with "ifconfig"

Comment: If you purchased a static IP then just type it into the "address" line I gave you an example of.  Ubuntu doesn't automatically know what static IPs you where assigned by your ISP.

Comment: yes, it seems reasonable what you say . thanks alot

Comment: Then please mark this as your answer.  Thanks.